# How to set indexes correctly Firestore Java

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have posts collection and I want to take all the posts that its "start" field is greater that current time and user_id not equal to "1".

```
Query query = firebaseFirestore
                .collection("posts")
                .whereNotEqualTo("user_id", "1")
                .whereGreaterThan("start", Timestamp.now());
```

I added index like on a screenshot, but still I get an error that I can’t use double condition.
What is wrong?[index screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBvNP.png)

Answer (score 1):

An index won't help you here.  The problem is that Firestore doesn't support the query you're trying to perform.  Please review the [documentation on query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) to better understand:

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Your query is using a range filter and an inequality filter on different fields, which is not supported.